# running "jupyter notebook" on terminal gives "-bash: jupyter: command not found": Without Anaconda on Mac

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter-notebook, macos-catalina

I have installed Python 3.8.4. Then installed pip by "sudo easy_install pip" on MacOS Catalina. I have two versions of python now (/usr/bin/python (2.7) and /usr/local/bin/python3). I run "pip install jupyterlab". Installed successfully but when I run "jupyter notebook" it says "-bash: jupyter: command not found". I want to install jupyter notebook without anaconda.

Comment: Can you include the output of `pip --version`. I think jupyter is using wrong interpreter.

Comment: pip 20.1.1 from /Users/soumen/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/pip (python 2.7) and my python3 is in:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3

Answer (score 1):

Thank **@tbhaxor**. I have fixed it. I have downloaded the "**get-pip.py**" from website https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ (copy and paste "**curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py**" on terminal). Then run "**sudo python3 get-pip.py**". It will ask admin password to install.